# Why did the cab dispatcher pick up Neal by his testicles?

Tags: plot-explanation, planes-trains-and-automobiles

In *Planes, Trains and Automobiles*, when Neal falls down and Del gets out of his car and tells the cab dispatcher to pick him up and he'll move his car, why did he pick up Neal by his testicles?

Comment: Because it's funny!

Answer (score 3):

One: It's funny.  That's true.

Two: If you want a guy to move quickly, you grab his testicles.  It's painful ([which is why it's funny](https://abcnews.go.com/Health/PainManagement/story?id=6325491&page=1)).  A man will do anything to rid himself of said pain, as quickly as possible.

Answer (score 2):

Neal had insulted the cab dispatcher by calling him a "slab of meat with mittens" and also insinuated that he had a very small penis ("If I wanted a joke I would follow you into the John and watch you take a leak"), so the dispatcher took the opportunity to get some payback by complying with Del's request, but doing it in a way that would cause the maximum amount of physical pain for Neal.

Also, funny.

Comment: This... this is the correct answer.